# Why is adding a method to a module handled differently to adding a submodule?

Tags: ruby, module

In the following example, module `M` is included in class `A` and, afterwards, re-opened to add a submodule `MM`, and a method. Then, it is included in class `B`:

```
module M
  def foo; "foo" end 
end

class A
  include M
end

module MM
  def baz; "baz" end 
end

module M
  include MM
  def bar; "bar" end 
end

class B
  include M
end
```

Instances of both `A` and `B` can access `M`'s method regardless of when they were added, but only `B` has the method of submodule `MM`:

```
a = A.new
a.foo
a.bar
a.baz # => Error: not defined

b = B.new
b.foo
b.bar
b.baz
```

I think this is inconsistent behaviour and would like to understand why this happens.

Comment: I can confirm that `a.baz` does not work in the following ruby versions `1.8.7`, `1.9.3`, `2.0.0`,`jruby-1.7.4`.

Comment: Someone commented it works in 2.0.0p353 but I just tested and it doesn't: `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]` gives `undefined method `baz' for #<A:0x0000000230b478> (NoMethodError)` (that comment has subsequently been removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `include` a module `M` into a class `C` with superclass `S`, this is what happens:

1. a class `M'` is created whose method table pointer, constant table pointer, instance variable table pointer and class variable table pointer point to `M`'s method table, constant table, instance variable table and class variable table.
2. `M'`s superclass pointer is set to `C`'s superclass (i.e. `S`)
3. `C`'s superclass pointer is set to `M'`

This process is repeated recursively for any modules mixed into `M` (and modules mixed into modules mixed into `M` and so forth).

This way, the linearization of the mixin hierarchy needs to only happen *once*, when you call `include`. The alternative (and this is what you seem to be expecting to happen) would be to perform this pretty expensive process for *every single method call*.

Comment: Ok, I get that. it was the pointer bit I was missing. I guess you're saying the ancestor chain is only built once and this is why `a` in my example can't run `baz` - because it wasn't there when its chain was built - but it can run `bar` because that's accessible over the already created pointer. Do I have that right?

Comment: +1 for awesome explanation. The only other great explanation on this topic I found was in the `Ruby under Microscope` book.

Comment: @jorg I can bet you this is *leak of the implementation.*... Is not it ?

Comment: @kirti +1 for pointer to [Ruby Under a Microscope](http://www.nostarch.com/rum). There is a one chapter [excerpt PDF](http://www.nostarch.com/download/samples/RUM_CH6_excerpt.pdf) which, as luck would have it, about this very subject. It's all explained in pages 151 through 155. It all makes sense now. I have to get that book.

Comment: @starfry Read the very same excerpt.